# Is it necessary to create two calendar instance for time in a java function?

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am working on an application where i have to find timestamp for 9 AM and 8 PM of each day and calculate that given timestamp is between these timestamp or not.
My function is given below, can anyone suggest me is it necessary to create two calendar instance ? and need help to optimize this function

```
 boolean isDateTimeBetweenNineAMTOEightPM(long datetime) {
    long nineAM = 0, eightPM = 0;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    nineAM = calendar.getTime().getTime() / 1000;

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    eightPM = calendar.getTime().getTime() / 1000;

    if (datetime >= nineAM && datetime <= eightPM) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to reuse them then, no, it is not necessary to get two instances. Just reuse the one you had.

Comment: Where are you using two instances?

Comment: For the simplicity I would recommend an external library called joda-time. Google for it. It will simplify code for you.

Comment: You don't require to set /*calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);*/ again, since you have already set for this instance. So, these two lines can also be removed.

Comment: From 9am to 8pm is 11 hours. Once you have the millis of 9 am you can check if your `datetime` is after that `time` and before `time` + 11 hours (= 39,600,000 ms).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); 
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    if (datetime < cal.getTimeInMillis()) {
        return false;
    }
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); 
    return datetime <= cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
boolean isDateTimeBetweenNineAMTOEightPM(
    long datetime) {
  final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get one calendar instance.
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);                 // Set Minutes, Seconds, and Millis to 0.
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);                   // 9 AM
  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
  final long nineAM = calendar.getTimeInMillis();   // In Millis.

  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);                   // 8 PM
  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
  return (datetime >= nineAM && datetime <= calendar
      .getTimeInMillis());                         // Return.
}
```